# How to output a table with rowspan from a MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem formatting a table. I got, from a query, a set of rows similar to this one:

```
5   23   d
5   23   d
5   23   t
5   24   d
5   24   t
4   23   d
4   23   t
```

Now, I want to display them in a table, but grouping similar data, something like this:

```
         d
5   23   d
         t
    24   d
         t
4   23   d
         t
```

So the `<td>` for 5 would be `<td rowspan='5'>` or the one for the first 23 would be `<td rowspan='3'>`. How can I achieve this?

I thought about making a multidimensional array storing a number for each rowspan, but the original set of rows is longer, so I got lost somewhere, and I guess there's a much easier solution.

Comment: Just the multidimentional array, and I had some ideas, but didn't try them because they wouldn't work (like checking if the last row was repeated, if so, add 1 to the rowspan... but that would be done after echoing the rowspan, so...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group the query result by column values. For example:

```
$grouped=array();
foreach($rows as $r)
  $grouped[ $r[0] ][ $r[1] ][]=$r[2];
```